# Getting the current date in visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

I dont know how to get the current date in visual basic 2008. Here is a sample code

```
regDate = Format(Date.Now(), "ddMMMyyyy")
```

The output is like 7/02/1900

Need help

Comment: Are you positive? `?Format(Date.Now(), "ddMMMyyyy") \ "07Feb2012"` what type is `regDate`

Comment: Well Date.Now() returns a date, there is no point in formatting it to a string then having `regDate` convert that string back to a date (option strict should warn about that)

Comment: most probably you used recently a time machine and you are still stuck in 1900.

Answer (score 27):

User can use this

```
Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```

this will format the date as required whereas user can change the string type dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy or yyyy/MM/dd or even can have this format to get the time from date

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
Dim regDate as Date = Date.Now()
Dim strDate as String = regDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy")
```

strDate will look like so: `07Feb2012`

Answer (score 2):

You may just want:

```
Dim regDate As Date = Date.Today()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need exact '/' delimiters, for example: 09/20/2013 rather than 09.20.2013, use escape sequence '/':

```
Dim regDate As Date = Date.Now()
Dim strDate As String = regDate.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim regDate As Date = Date.Now.date
```

This should fix your problem, though it's 2 years old!

Comment: Why not save a step and use `Date.Today()`