# Get the current date and time

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to get the current date and time.

For example:

```
2012/11/13 06:30:38
```

What I have tried:

```
Dim d As System.DateTime
MsgBox(d.Year) 'Return 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the current date in visual Basic 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177199/getting-the-current-date-in-visual-basic-2008)

Answer (score 80):

use `DateTime.Now`

**try this:**

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: You can also use "d" for the format string to use the system date-time format.

Answer (score 15):

Try this one:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 4):

`DateTimePicker1.value = Format(Date.Now)`

Answer (score 4):

Get Current DateTime

```
Now.ToShortDateString()
DateTime.Now
Today.Now
```